# how to redirect to a url stored in the database Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, paperclip

I want to redirect to the pdf that the user upload.

so in the browser when i go to /news_article/3 i want it to show the pdf, the path to the pdf is stored in the database how can i redirect to it?

in my show action in the controller `@news_article = NewsArticle.find(params[:id])`

**model**

```
class AddAttachPaperclipToNewsArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :news_articles, :attach_file_name, :string
    add_column :news_articles, :attach_content_type, :string
    add_column :news_articles, :attach_file_size, :integer
    add_column :news_articles, :attach_updated_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

in pry if i do `@news_article.attach` it gives me the path to the pdf, but how can I get browser to display the pdf? when i try to `redirect_to @news_article.attach` in the controller, it says undefined method 'model_name' for paperclip::attachment:class.

why is this?

Thank you :)

Comment: I think papperclip has methods like `@news_article.attach.url` (see doc here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#quick-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do this is in the controller for the news_article in `def show` you write `redirect_to @news_article.attach.url`

in news_article paperclip store url in attach (I call it this in model) and the .url helper is what makes the browser go there :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like @news_article.attach is returning the paperclip::attachment object to you. As the deafult to_s method of paperclip::attachment class is the url, you are seeing the pdf path when to evaluate it separately. But actually it is not the "String" path. So, in the redirect call , try giving the string path, by explicitly calling to_s on @news_article.attach like redirect_to @news_article.attach.to_s